# Creating a List of Toggle From a Set Using ForEach in swiftui

Tags: swiftui

I' trying to create a set of Toggles, that need to be stored in one core data field of type "Transformable". I started with this example:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118595
in combination with other ideas from stack.

I'm trying to get this way:

- Create a Set of structs like this

```
struct AllScopes: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var notify: Bool
}

[...]
// all the stuff with View and body with 

@State var scopes = Set<AllScopes>()

[...]
// and here I run through my FetchRequest to fill the Set
.onAppear {
    for scope in allScopes {
        scopes.insert(
            AllScopes(
                id: scope.id!,
                name: scope.name!,
                notify: false
            )
        )
    }
}
```

In the end I've got a nice Set with all my scopes.

I call a new View with `YearlyReportPage6(scopes: $scopes)`

And now my problem - the next view:

```
struct YearlyReportPage6: View {
    
    @Binding var scopes: Set<AllScopes>
    
    init(scopes: Binding<Set<AllScopes>>) {
        _scopes = scopes
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(scopes.indices) { index in
                Toggle(isOn: self.$scopes[index].notify) {
                    Text(self.scopes[index].name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But all in ForEach creates errors. Either Binding in `isOn:` is wrong, or ForEach can't work with the set, or the Text is not a String, or, or, or...
In the end there should be a list of Toggles (checkboxes) and the selection should be stored in database.

Changing the Set into a simple Array like `@State var scopes = [AllScopes]()` will work for the Toggles, but how can I store this into a `Transformable`?

```
ForEach(Array(scopes).indices) { index in
    Toggle(isOn: self.$scopes[index].notify) {
        Text(self.scopes[index].name)
    }
}
```

[image: Result how Toggles should look like]

To summarize:

- either how can I create the list of Toggles with the Set of AllScopes
- or how can I store the Array / Dictionary into the Transformable field?

I hope, you can understand my clumsy English. :-)

Comment: You don't need intermediate struct, work with core data object directly, it is observable object, so Toggle can bind to its property.

Comment: I try to JSONencode / decode the "Array" and store it to a String-field.

Comment: @Asperi: hmm, I will think about it. I think the problem ist, that I don't need the objects themsevels be changed. I need the objects as a kind of "template" for another Entitiy, being stored in one field. Will mean: I have to create a yearly report on my clients and must select, which scopes will fit to this client.

Comment: Watch Demystifying SwiftUI, you shouldn’t use the index

Comment: The above comments are correct with regard to the view. With regard to the Core Data question, you are asking for problems trying to store "AllScopes" as a "Transformable". The better model for core data is to create an `AllScopes` entity, and link it to your other entity with a one to many relationship. Essentially, you are modeling that the Client entity has an array of AllScopes entity, which I believe is what you are looking for. 9999 times out of 10000 you want to model this as a relationship.

Comment: Thanks for all your precious help. Off course relationships would be a solution, but imo relationships are only good in small databases. In huge apps (that's what I've read somewhere about core data) a good mixture of relationships (e.g. types of things, categories e.a.) and manual relations (connecting by id manually) I think is better. (but this is a matter of taste and performance) Perhaps in this special case, a relationship might be better. I'll think about it and change it.